# writing a new cell to a sheet apache poi

Tags: java, selenium, junit, apache-poi

i am using following code, for reading a excel using apache poi, its a .xlsx file. Please let me know what i can do, to also alter a value of a cell, in each row as my loop keeps going. Thanks

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

String fileName = "C:/createCDN.xlsx";
FileInputStream fis = null;
fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileName);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
int totalRows=sheet.getLastRowNum();
for(int i=1;i<=totalRows;i++) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
    method.fillTextBox(row.getCell(0),"name", pageProp);
    method.fillTextBox(row.getCell(0),"name", pageProp);
} //Do something here, or inside loop to write to lets say cell(2) of same row.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
    if (cell == null) {
        cell = row.createCell(2);
    }
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("some value");
}
```

To save the workbook you could just write:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

You should take a look at [POI's Busy Developers' Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

Comment: I did that, i think for that I also need to create one fileoutstream, as i only created instream, also after i do all the changes in the cells and loop is over, i need to close the outstream. please suggest, it was giving me error,

Comment: Thanks, that works.. all i had to is that, but needed to be done, after loop is finished. thanks for the link too, its great.

Comment: In the Busy Developers Guide they use `row.createCell(2).setCellValue( createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string") );` rather than `cell.setCellValue("This is a string");`. Anyone know what's going on there?

Comment: @Rory Simple: the first line is for setting "rich text" string value, and the second line is for setting ordinary string value.

Answer (score 1):

at first you need to create the space in the excel file, like this:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 10 ; row++) {
    sheet.createRow(row);
    for(int column = 0; column < 10; column++) { 
        sheet.getRow(row).createCell(column);                
    }                
}
```

then you can write the excel using this command:

```
sheet.getRow(row).getCell(column).setCellValue("hello");
```