# Add cell to existing Apache Poi row

Tags: apache-poi

I have existing Apache POI Row, and I want to add a cell to it, but as far as I understood when I create a cell on that row it doesn't reflect on the sheet, like I have to save the changes.

```
final Row row = sheet.getRow(index);
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1); // doesn't reflect on sheet itself
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [writing a new cell to a sheet apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754641/writing-a-new-cell-to-a-sheet-apache-poi)

Comment: Also see this ["creating cells" example](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells).